# SQL Server Full Text Search: how do I get a full column match

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I'm trying to find records where a column value is part of a param.

Normally I would use a like search but this is to slow.

Data:

```
1 | Jungle Road
2 | Long Road
3 | Small Road
```

SQL:

```
DECLARE @c nvarchar(512) = 'My Street: Jungle Road My Nr: 8'
SELECT Id, StreetName FROM Customers WHERE @c like '%' + StreetName + '%'
```

Result:

```
1 | Jungle Road
```

When using the following @c value 'My Street: Jungle My Nr: 8' (so without 'Road') I don't get any records (as aspected).

But because a like is to slow, I'm trying to use Full-Text search.

```
SELECT Id, StreetName FROM Customers WHERE FREETEXT(StreetName, @c)
```

Result with @c = 'My Street: Jungle Road My Nr: 8':

```
1 | Jungle Road
```

Now with @c 'My Street: Jungle My Nr: 8' (without 'Road') the result is still:

```
1 | Jungle Road
```

**Question:**

How do I change the Full-Text search to a full match search instead of partial word search? So I only get a result when the full column value is part of the param?

I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Just add `[` after the first `%`

Comment: If I understand your Q verry well my A should answer it.

Comment: Why can't you extract the proper search string from `@c` ?

Comment: The @c is a free field "description" that a customer fills in (it can contain multiple values like streetname, customerName, InvoiceNr, etc). I need to search in this string for a streetname. When found I know the customer(s).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST (
ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
StreetName NVARCHAR(512) NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES
('Jungle Road'),('Long Road'),('Small Road'),('My Street: Jungle Road My Nr: 8');

DECLARE @c nvarchar(512) = 'My Street: Jungle Road My Nr: 8';
SELECT Id, StreetName FROM #TEST WHERE @c like '%[' + StreetName + '%';
```

Resault :

```
Id          StreetName
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4           My Street: Jungle Road My Nr: 8
```

Just for more :

```
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES
('My Street: Jungle Road My Nr: 8 bbbb');

DECLARE @c nvarchar(512) = 'My Street: Jungle Road My Nr: 8';
SELECT Id, StreetName FROM #TEST WHERE @c like '%[' + StreetName + '%';
```

The resault :

```
Id          StreetName
----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4           My Street: Jungle Road My Nr: 8
5           My Street: Jungle Road My Nr: 8 bbbb
```

Comment: But what I need is result ID 1 when using a string containing "Jungle Road" and No result when using a string "Jungle" (without "Road"). And not ID 4 or 5.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you want the result for `Jungle Road` but no result for `Jungle` or `Road` alone you would use FULLTEXT query with `AND` operator like this:

```
DECLARE @c nvarchar(512) = '"Jungle" and "Road"'
SELECT Id, StreetName FROM Customers WHERE CONTAINS(StreetName, @c)
```

[CONTAINS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) is more precise than [FREETEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx) and the above query will return only records containing both `Jungle` and 'Road'.

But, it will work for you ONLY **if you are able to extract the exact search terms** from the search string typed in by users, just as @SqlZim suggested. You would have to build the actual FULLTEXT search term by concatenating individual words with `and` just as the `@c` variable above looks like.

If you don't want/can't split the user input into search words then the best you could do is to order your FULLTEXT query results by rank and let users choose the best matching client something like this:

```
DECLARE @c nvarchar(512) = 'My Street: Jungle Road My Nr: 8'
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [KEY],[Rank] from FREETEXTTABLE(Customers, StreetName, @c, 10)
) 
SELECT c.* from cte
    INNER JOIN Customers c on cte.[Key]=c.Id
```

The last parameter to `FREETEXTTABLE` 10 tells SQL Server to select TOP 10 best matching records for your search string `@c`.

Try replacing [FREETEXTTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx) with [CONTAINSTABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx) and see the difference.

HTH.